# assign same value to static variable in different thread, still need lock?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, static-methods

```
public class Service
{
   private List<SomeType> _list = null;
   public static List<SomeType> GetSomeTypeList()
   {
      if (_list != null) return _list;
      List<SomeType> _temp = null;
      _temp = FunctionToGetSomeTypeValue();
      _list = _temp;
      return _list;
   }
}
```

It's server code, `GetSomeTypeList` may be called by multiple requests (threads), the return result of `FunctionToGetSomeTypeValue` will be the same even in different thread, it's a static resource, but `FunctionToGetSomeTypeValue` may fail by return null. 
My intention is to get the resource when it's needed and try to get it every time it's called, unless it is a success.
The question is when updating `_list`, `_list = _temp`, do I need to lock using `lock(lockobj) {_list=_temp}`?

if two threads are calling `GetSomeTypeList()`, and both goes to call `FunctionToGetSomeTypeValue()`, one is success, one is failed, the success one call `_list=_temp` first, failed one then assign `_list=null`. I'm fine with this case, because eventually `_list` will be in a good state, and all calls just return `_list`.

Thing I don't understand is if I don't use lock, is there any chance `_list` object be assigned a incorrect value (a unexpected value)? Not null, neither correct `_temp` with correct address.

so the actual question is, assume there's variable: `static int Obj = 0;`

- one thread is setting `Obj = 1;`
- another thread is setting `Obj = 2;`

if there's no lock over setting of `Obj`, value of `Obj` should be either 1 or 2, won't be anything else, is that correct?
what if `Obj` is a `struct`?

Is assignment of reference object (address) a atomic operation ?
What about simple type `object(int, struct)`?

Comment: Setting a reference is atomic.

Comment: Is there a problem with using a `lock`?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, there exists a Framework class, `Lazy<T>`, that allows for this lazy instantiation of objects in a thread-safe manner.  There is no need to write your own:

```
public class Service
{
   private static Lazy<List<SomeType>> _list = new Lazy<List<SomeType>>(
       ()=>FunctionToGetSomeTypeValue(),
       isThreadSafe: true
   );

   public static List<SomeType> GetSomeTypeList()
   {
      return _list.Value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Right, no need to reinvent the wheel. Rule 1 of thread synchronization: Don't do it. Use higher-level tools that do it for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a reference is atomic, so `_list` will always be a valid reference. `GetSomeTypeList()` will always return a reference to `List<SomeType>` or a `null`.

However, it is possible that 2 threads call it at the same time, both get past the `if (_list != null)` condition and receive different instances of `List<SomeType>`.

I'd rather put a `lock` there

```
public static List<SomeType> GetSomeTypeList()
{
    if (_list == null)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_list == null)
            {
                _list = FunctionToGetSomeTypeValue();
            }
        }
    }
    return _list;
}
```

Or, if you don't like `lock`, `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to assign a new value to `_list` only if it's still null

```
public static List<SomeType> GetSomeTypeList()
{
    if (_list == null)
    {
        var temp = FunctionToGetSomeTypeValue();
        Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _list, temp, null);
    }
    return _list;
}
```

Note that in both cases the first check `if (_list == null)` is done without any thread synchronization. Once a value is assigned to `_list`, it can be retrieved safely without synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks already pointed out, setting a reference is an atomic operation, i.e. in the case you mentioned there cannot be invalid values. It is only a question which assignment will "win", but it always will be a complete assignment.

The same is true e.g. for int, but in general NOT for structs.

C# language specification:

> 5.5 Atomicity of variable references
>
> Reads and writes of the following data types are atomic: `bool`, `char`, `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `uint`, `int`, `float`, and reference types. In addition, reads and writes of enum types with an underlying type in the previous list are also atomic. Reads and writes of other types, including `long`, `ulong`, `double`, and `decimal`, as well as user-defined types, are not guaranteed to be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `lock`, but at least a null check around the end of that method.

There could be two threads calling your `FunctionToGetSomeValueType` at the same time. If the first is successful, `_list` will be set to the result. When the second fails a little later, it may reset it to `null`.

```
private static object syncLock = new object ();
public static List<SomeType> GetSomeTypeList()
{
    if (_list != null) return _list;
    List<SomeType> _temp = FunctionToGetSomeTypeValue();
    if  (_temp != null) // check this! 
        _list = _temp;
    return _list;
}
```